# fazer as imagens desaparecerem dependendo do select

Tags: javascript, html, css

Olá

Eu criei um filtro que basicamente lê o meu json e diz o numero de vitimas que há ao todo dependendo das opções seleccionadas no filtro.

Usando esse filtro queria remover alguns bonecos que estão do lado direito igualando até ao numero de vitimas encontradas, algo que não sei fazer...

obs: nao sei o que se passa mas cada vez que tento adicionar um pouco de script dentro botão, o botão para de funcionar.

**Imagem do meu site:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**o script que usei para fazer o filtro foi este:**

```js
var json = [{
    "Nome": "Lucia Rodrigues",
    "Idade": 48,
    "Distrito": "Faro",
    "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
    "Faixa": "faixaD",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Sim"
},
{
    "Nome": "Nome Desconhecido",
    "Idade": 46,
    "Distrito": "Açores",
    "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
    "Faixa": "faixaD",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Não"
},
{
    "Nome": "Vera Silva",
    "Idade": 30,
    "Distrito": "Setúbal",
    "Faixa Etaria": "26-35",
    "Faixa": "faixaC",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Não"
},
{
    "Nome": "Maria Eufrázia",
    "Idade": 83,
    "Distrito": "Évora",
    "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
    "Faixa": "faixaD",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Sim"
},
{
    "Nome": "Luzia Rosado",
    "Idade": 80,
    "Distrito": "Évora",
    "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
    "Faixa": "faixaD",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Sim"
},
{
    "Nome": "Fernanda",
    "Idade": 70,
    "Distrito": "Lisboa",
    "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
    "Faixa": "faixaD",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Sim"
},
{
    "Nome": "Nome Desconhecido",
    "Idade": 48,
    "Distrito": "Açores",
    "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
    "Faixa": "faixaD",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Não"
},
{
    "Nome": "Marina Mendes",
    "Idade": 25,
    "Distrito": "Viseu",
    "Faixa Etaria": "18-25",
    "Faixa": "faixaB",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Sim"
},
{
    "Nome": "Helena Cabrita",
    "Idade": 60,
    "Distrito": "Madeira",
    "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
    "Faixa": "faixaD",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Sim"
},
{
    "Nome": "Lana",
    "Idade": 2,
    "Distrito": "Madeira",
    "Faixa Etaria": "0-17",
    "Faixa": "faixaA",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Sim"
},
{
    "Nome": "Fernando Cruz",
    "Idade": 60,
    "Distrito": "Porto",
    "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
    "Faixa": "faixaD",
    "Sexo": "Masc",
    "RecursoArma": "Não"
},
{
    "Nome": "Ana Maria Silva",
    "Idade": 53,
    "Distrito": "Açores",
    "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
    "Faixa": "faixaD",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Sim"
},
{
    "Nome": "Ana Paula",
    "Idade": 40,
    "Distrito": "Braga",
    "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
    "Faixa": "faixaD",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Não"
},
{
    "Nome": "Heila Lopes",
    "Idade": 44,
    "Distrito": "Lisboa",
    "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
    "Faixa": "faixaD",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Não"
}]

$("#btnBuscar").click(function() {
            var filtroFaixaEtaria = $("#FaixaEtaria option:selected").text();
            var filtroSexo = $("#Sexo option:selected").text();
            var filtroRecursoArma = $("#RecursoArma option:selected").text();
            var filtroDistrito = $("#Distrito option:selected").text();
 
        var arrayResultados = json.filter(function(item) {
        var criteria = true;
    
    if (filtroFaixaEtaria != null && filtroFaixaEtaria != "")
     criteria = criteria && item["Faixa Etaria"] == filtroFaixaEtaria;
    if (filtroSexo != null && filtroSexo != "")
     criteria = criteria && item["Sexo"] == filtroSexo;
    if (filtroRecursoArma != null && filtroRecursoArma != "")
     criteria = criteria && item["RecursoArma"] == filtroRecursoArma;
    if (filtroDistrito != null && filtroDistrito !="")
        criteria = criteria &&item["Distrito"] == filtroDistrito;

    return criteria;

  });

  alert("Foram encontrados " + arrayResultados.length + " elementos de acordo com a busca");

});
```

**HTML dos selects e das imagens**

```html
    Faixa Etaria:  
    <select id="FaixaEtaria" class="custom-select">
        <option></option>
        <option value="1">0-17</option>
        <option value="2">18-25</option>
        <option value="3">26-35</option>
        <option value="4">36 ou mais</option>
    </select>

    <br/>
    <br/>
 
    Sexo:
    <select id="Sexo" class="custom-select">
        <option></option>
        <option value="5">Masc</option>
        <option value="6">Fem</option>
    </select>

    <br/>
    <br/>

    Recurso a arma:
    <select id="RecursoArma" class="custom-select">
        <option></option>
        <option value="7">Sim</option>
        <option value="8">Não</option>
    </select>


    <br/>
    <br/>

    Localidade:
    <select id="Distrito" class="custom-select">
        <option ></option>
        <option value="9">Viana do Castelo</option>
        <option value="10">Vila Real</option>
        <option value="11">Bragança</option>
        <option value="12">Braga</option>
        <option value="13">Porto</option>
        <option value="14">Aveiro</option>
        <option value="15">Viseu</option>
        <option value="16">Guarda</option>
        <option value="17">Coimbra</option>
        <option value="18">Castelo Branco</option>
        <option value="19">Leiria</option>
        <option value="20">Lisboa</option>
        <option value="21">Santarém</option>
        <option value="22">Portalegre</option>
        <option value="23">Évora</option>
        <option value="24">Setúbal</option>
        <option value="25">Beja</option>
        <option value="26">Faro</option>
        <option value="27">Açores</option>
        <option value="28">Madeira</option>
    </select>

<br>

<button id="btnBuscar">Filtrar</button>

<br>
    
    <img class="imagens" id="imgA" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
    <img class="imagens" id="imgB" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
    <img class="imagens" id="imgC" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
    <img class="imagens" id="imgD" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
    <img class="imagens" id="imgE" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
    <img class="imagens" id="imgF" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
    <img class="imagens" id="imgG" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
    <img class="imagens" id="imgH" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
    <img class="imagens" id="imgI" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
    <img class="imagens" id="imgJ" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
    <img class="imagens" id="imgK" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
    <img class="imagens" id="imgL" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
    <img class="imagens" id="imgM" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
    <img class="imagens" id="imgN" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes gerar esses bonecos a cada vez que o valor do boneco muda...

Algo assim:

```js
const urlIcon = 'https://1001freedownloads.s3.amazonaws.com/vector/thumb/74889/1367934593.png';
const imagem = `<img src="${urlIcon}" />`;

var json = [{
    "Nome": "Lucia Rodrigues",
    "Idade": 48,
    "Distrito": "Faro",
    "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
    "Faixa": "faixaD",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Sim"
  },
  {
    "Nome": "Nome Desconhecido",
    "Idade": 46,
    "Distrito": "Açores",
    "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
    "Faixa": "faixaD",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Não"
  },
  {
    "Nome": "Vera Silva",
    "Idade": 30,
    "Distrito": "Setúbal",
    "Faixa Etaria": "26-35",
    "Faixa": "faixaC",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Não"
  },
  {
    "Nome": "Maria Eufrázia",
    "Idade": 83,
    "Distrito": "Évora",
    "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
    "Faixa": "faixaD",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Sim"
  },
  {
    "Nome": "Luzia Rosado",
    "Idade": 80,
    "Distrito": "Évora",
    "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
    "Faixa": "faixaD",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Sim"
  },
  {
    "Nome": "Fernanda",
    "Idade": 70,
    "Distrito": "Lisboa",
    "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
    "Faixa": "faixaD",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Sim"
  },
  {
    "Nome": "Nome Desconhecido",
    "Idade": 48,
    "Distrito": "Açores",
    "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
    "Faixa": "faixaD",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Não"
  },
  {
    "Nome": "Marina Mendes",
    "Idade": 25,
    "Distrito": "Viseu",
    "Faixa Etaria": "18-25",
    "Faixa": "faixaB",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Sim"
  },
  {
    "Nome": "Helena Cabrita",
    "Idade": 60,
    "Distrito": "Madeira",
    "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
    "Faixa": "faixaD",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Sim"
  },
  {
    "Nome": "Lana",
    "Idade": 2,
    "Distrito": "Madeira",
    "Faixa Etaria": "0-17",
    "Faixa": "faixaA",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Sim"
  },
  {
    "Nome": "Fernando Cruz",
    "Idade": 60,
    "Distrito": "Porto",
    "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
    "Faixa": "faixaD",
    "Sexo": "Masc",
    "RecursoArma": "Não"
  },
  {
    "Nome": "Ana Maria Silva",
    "Idade": 53,
    "Distrito": "Açores",
    "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
    "Faixa": "faixaD",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Sim"
  },
  {
    "Nome": "Ana Paula",
    "Idade": 40,
    "Distrito": "Braga",
    "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
    "Faixa": "faixaD",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Não"
  },
  {
    "Nome": "Heila Lopes",
    "Idade": 44,
    "Distrito": "Lisboa",
    "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
    "Faixa": "faixaD",
    "Sexo": "Fem",
    "RecursoArma": "Não"
  }
]

$("#btnBuscar").click(function() {
  var filtroFaixaEtaria = $("#FaixaEtaria option:selected").text();
  var filtroSexo = $("#Sexo option:selected").text();
  var filtroRecursoArma = $("#RecursoArma option:selected").text();
  var filtroDistrito = $("#Distrito option:selected").text();

  var arrayResultados = json.filter(function(item) {
    var criteria = true;

    if (filtroFaixaEtaria != null && filtroFaixaEtaria != "")
      criteria = criteria && item["Faixa Etaria"] == filtroFaixaEtaria;
    if (filtroSexo != null && filtroSexo != "")
      criteria = criteria && item["Sexo"] == filtroSexo;
    if (filtroRecursoArma != null && filtroRecursoArma != "")
      criteria = criteria && item["RecursoArma"] == filtroRecursoArma;
    if (filtroDistrito != null && filtroDistrito != "")
      criteria = criteria && item["Distrito"] == filtroDistrito;

    return criteria;

  });

  console.log("Foram encontrados " + arrayResultados.length + " elementos de acordo com a busca");
  const imagens = Array.from({
    length: Number(arrayResultados.length)
  }).reduce((html) => html + imagem, '');
  $('#images').html(imagens);

});
```

```css
#images {
  margin: 20px;
}

#images img {
  height: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Faixa Etaria:
<select id="FaixaEtaria" class="custom-select">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">0-17</option>
  <option value="2">18-25</option>
  <option value="3">26-35</option>
  <option value="4">36 ou mais</option>
</select>

<br/>
<br/> Sexo:
<select id="Sexo" class="custom-select">
  <option></option>
  <option value="5">Masc</option>
  <option value="6">Fem</option>
</select>

<br/>
<br/> Recurso a arma:
<select id="RecursoArma" class="custom-select">
  <option></option>
  <option value="7">Sim</option>
  <option value="8">Não</option>
</select>


<br/>
<br/> Localidade:
<select id="Distrito" class="custom-select">
  <option></option>
  <option value="9">Viana do Castelo</option>
  <option value="10">Vila Real</option>
  <option value="11">Bragança</option>
  <option value="12">Braga</option>
  <option value="13">Porto</option>
  <option value="14">Aveiro</option>
  <option value="15">Viseu</option>
  <option value="16">Guarda</option>
  <option value="17">Coimbra</option>
  <option value="18">Castelo Branco</option>
  <option value="19">Leiria</option>
  <option value="20">Lisboa</option>
  <option value="21">Santarém</option>
  <option value="22">Portalegre</option>
  <option value="23">Évora</option>
  <option value="24">Setúbal</option>
  <option value="25">Beja</option>
  <option value="26">Faro</option>
  <option value="27">Açores</option>
  <option value="28">Madeira</option>
</select>

<br>

<button id="btnBuscar">Filtrar</button>

<br>

<div id="images"></div>

<!--
  <img class="imagens" id="imgA" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
  <img class="imagens" id="imgB" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
  <img class="imagens" id="imgC" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
  <img class="imagens" id="imgD" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
  <img class="imagens" id="imgE" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
  <img class="imagens" id="imgF" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
  <img class="imagens" id="imgG" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
  <img class="imagens" id="imgH" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
  <img class="imagens" id="imgI" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
  <img class="imagens" id="imgJ" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
  <img class="imagens" id="imgK" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
  <img class="imagens" id="imgL" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
  <img class="imagens" id="imgM" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
  <img class="imagens" id="imgN" src="/imagens/personagem4.png" height="55px" width="27px">
-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Boa dia!

Provavelmente o que queres fazer é algo do género: crias uma condição (`WHERE`) onde o `numero_imagens = numero_vitimas`

Todos os nomes que utilizei são apenas exemplos...